# Python Jira cannot transition_issue and throws exception

Tags: python, jira

I tried to transition the jira issue to `closed` status, the code is:

```
jira.create_issue_link('Duplicate', issue, issueJ, None)
jira.transition_issue(issueJ.key, '181')
query.remove(issueJ)
```

The first sentence works, it creates a link. But the transition_issue not works and it throws and exception:

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.net/rest/api/2/issue/ticket.number/transitions
text: The selected resolution cannot be chosen during this action.

response headers = {'Server': 'nginx/1.10.3', 'Date': 'Wed, 20 Mar 2019 09:37:33 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-AREQUESTID': '577x474155x4', 'X-ASESSIONID': '1fwn7w3', 'X-ANODEID': 'prd-dops-issues-ap-02', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self'", 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-11553968', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'gongjunh', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'User-Agent'}
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"resolution":"The selected resolution cannot be chosen during this action."}}
```

I confirmed that I can transition the status of the issue on the jira page, but I am not sure why the exception occurs in the code.

Comment: 400... your request is invalid

Comment: @Kendoka the examples in the api doc here just like this: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Well in Jira, each Queue can have different configuration. In transitions, each queue defines which are the states(close, In Progress, Solved etc) can be possible from Open state.

Below is one sample configuration:
[image: Sample jira queue configuration for transitions]

You can not mark any other state/transition which is not allowed.
There is an API available: transitions(issue_id) (in python, the one you are using)

WHich will list all the possible transitions can be done from current state. The state that you want to move in, is probably not in that list.

Try this.

Comment: I just used the transitions(issue_id) and found the transition id which I want. The problem is solved by using jira.transition_issue(issue, 181, fields={'resolution':{'id': '3'}})

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your workflow in Jira, in my case it is like this:

[image]

So, before marking pass or fail i need to transit through other intermediate stages as well. So, e.g. if testcase or testrun is in New state. Then transition will be as below,

```
    jira = JIRA(options="Jira_Server_URL", basic_auth=("userID", "Password"))
    jira.transition_issue(issue, transition='Ready For Test')
    jira.transition_issue(issue, transition='Test in Progress')
    jira.transition_issue(issue, transition='Pass')
```

Replace Jira_Server_URL, userID, Password and transition accordingly.